# Cannot access tomcat 8 using external ip address

Tags: tomcat, external-ip, external-connection, tomcat8

I deployed an web app using Tomcat8 listening to TCP-8080 on a Windows 7. It works fine on my internal network.

However, I wanted to access it remotely too, so I searched a little bit for the configurations needed, and did as follows:

1) Created rules to enable traffic on port 8080;

2) Edited the server.xml to add the "address" attribute:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           address="0.0.0.0"               />
```

3) Temporarily disabled the internal firewall on my router.

But I still can't access my application externally. I also tried to disable the Windows firewall entirely, but nothing seems to work.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

you need to forward port from  your router to your deployed machine.in router setting option  something like "Virtual Servers" or "Forwarding"(depends on router model).

for example if your deployed machine IP is 192.168.0.104 .

```
ID  Service Port    Internal Port   IP Address      Protocol        
1   8080                    8080    192.168.0.104     TCP
```